# Input param passing in query stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

How to pass IN variable in query dynamically. Example is as below (using oracle db ) :
I want to check whether num_pattern pattern is matching with CALLNUM.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EXECUTE_CDIV
( 
  CALLNUM IN VARCHAR2, 
  RESULT OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
     select count(1) into RESULT 
      from datatable 
      where num_pattern like 'CALLNUM%' ;
END;
```

Comment: Just try this `...where num_pattern like CALLNUM||'%' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select count(*) into RESULT from datatable 
where num_pattern like CALLNUM||'%'
```

Comment: It could be better to use `RESULT` instead of `CNT`, looks like there is mistake in author query, it's just guess

Comment: @agent5566:- Yes, I have updated it as `*` instead of `1`.

Comment: I mean `select count(*) into RESULT`

Answer (score 0):

If available, why not use REGEXP_LIKE instead of like so that you don't need to put that % in your query..also its more powerful than LIKE operator

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EXECUTE_CDIV
( 
  CALLNUM IN VARCHAR2, 
  RESULT OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
     select count(1) into RESULT 
      from datatable 
      where regexp_like(num_pattern, CALLNUM );
END;
/
```

Refer to the documentation where you can put more options if this need to be case sensitive search ...
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php

http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11741.html